# How to color code Lattice sites using 3d matrix of size (4,4,16) in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, lattices

```
cell = LatticeData["SimpleCubic", "Image"];
Graphics3D[Translate[cell[[1]], 2 Tuples[Range[3], 3]],   Boxed -> False]
```

I know this creates 4x4x4 lattice; how can I make it to graph 4x4x16 lattice?
I have created a simple cubic lattice using graphics. Now, I wanna color code these points using (4,4,16) matrix containing 1's and 0's. So, my question is how can I do this?

[image: I have created this plot using Python Scatter plot but I am trying to find a better way to visualize this using matthematica]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a $4 \times 4\times 16$ binary matrix using `RandomInteger` and replace `0`s with `Red` and `1`s with `Green`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
matrix = RandomInteger[1, {4, 4, 16}] /. {0 -> Red, 1 -> Green};
```

Use `MapIndexed` with level specification `{3}` to combine colors in `matrix` with spheres and cuboids placed in coordinates given by the index:

```
spheres = MapIndexed[{#, Sphere[#2, .15]} &, matrix, {3}];

cuboids =  MapIndexed[Cuboid @ #2 &, matrix[[;; -2, ;; -2, ;; -2]], {3}];

Graphics3D[{spheres, FaceForm[{Opacity[.1], Blue}], cuboids}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, generate coordinates using `Outer` and combine the coordinates with the colors from `matrix` using `MapThread`:

```
coords = Outer[List, Range[4], Range[4], Range[16]];

spheres = MapThread[{#, Sphere[#2, .15]} &, {matrix, coords}, 3];

cuboids = Map[Cuboid, coords[[;;-2, ;;-2, ;;-2]], {-2}];

Graphics3D[{spheres, FaceForm[{Opacity[.1], Blue}], cuboids}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can use `RandomChoice` to get the 3D array of colors directly:

```
SeedRandom[1];
matrix2 = RandomChoice[{Red, Green}, {4, 4, 16}];

matrix2 == matrix
```

> True

Comment: Very cute  indeed :-)